# Rails has many and belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am building a daily deal app to better learn Ruby on Rails.

On M. Hartly tutorial, I understood the concept of models and their relationship (a microposts belongs_to a user, and a user has_many microposts).

However I am not sure how to put that into practice on my daily deal project.

I decided to have a Model for users with two type of users with different rights:

- admin_user who can create/update/edit/delete the deals
- standard_user who can see the deals and if they find one interesting participate in a deal

Both users go into the users database

I also decided to have a model for deals and go in the Deals database
So have I understood well:

- a admin_user has_many deals
- deals belongs to a admin_user
- standard_user has many deals (indeed he can participate in many deals)
- and deals do NOT belong to standard_user so I can’t say anything here.

Have I understood things right? It is possible to define according to the type of right of a user different relationship to a model object(in this case: deals)

PS: I think I’ll separate users with cancan gem to give them different rights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue with what you're describing is that a standard_user `has_many :deals`, but deals don't belong to a standard_user; they probably are in use by many standard users at the same time.  That means that a deal can't `belong_to` a standard_user, because you can't have a `standard_user_id` column in your Deals table (since you'd need arbitrarily many columns to deal with the arbitrarily many users who might participate).

In order to have a many-to-many relationship like this, you need a link table.  Here's one way to achieve this in Rails:

```
class DealParticipation < ActiveRecord:Base
  #This means the deal_participations table has a standard_user_id key
  belongs_to :standard_user
  #This means the deal_participations table has a deal_id key
  belongs_to :deal

  #... more logic goes here ...
end
```

Now your standard user looks like:

```
class StandardUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_participations
  has_many :deals, :through => :deal_participations
  # ... more logic goes here ...
end
```

And your deal class looks like:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_participations
  has_many :standard_users, :through => :deal_participations
  belongs_to :admin_user
  #... more logic goes here ...
end
```

You'll then need three tables: one for `deals`, one for `deal_participations`, and one for `standard_users` (plus the stuff for admin users).

Depending on your needs, you may also want to try using single-table inheritance (STI) to make Users and Admin Users derive from a common base class.  You can read more about STI [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

I hope that helps!  Enjoy getting started with Rails!

Comment: I see what the attributes of the users table look like :user_id/user_login/user_password/user_location.I also see the deals table attributes:deals_name, deals_price...BUT i don't understand what i'd put in the deals_participations table you mention. what would be the attributes (columns) of that table ? If they are: deals_participation_id/user_id/deals_id, i would have a number of lines equal to the number of user multiplied by the number of deals they participate in...which could be enormous and seems uneffective. Am I wrong about the deals_participation table attributes?

Comment: The columns of the deals_participations table are indeed what you describe.  There's one row for each time a user participates in a deal.  This is exactly the same amount of data as you would have if you stored a list of the deals a user participates in on the user (but if you did that, then you couldn't query on it).  This "link table" design is very much the standard approach to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand. The main thing is that I need to be able to retrieve the data “which deals the user mathieu45 (example) participated in the last 30 days” in order to customize emails to him. I fear that querying this table will be far too long and inefficient for this.

Comment: I posted a new question to more clearly seperate this different issue=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215150/customize-deals-apps-homepage-and-emails-thanks-to-user-history-how-to-do-it-t

Comment: The query "Which deals did mathieu45 participate in in the last 30 days" should be *extremely* fast with the above layout, provided that you have put the correct indexes on your tables.  Databases are really, really good at doing this sort of thing quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each deal is associated with a single admin_user, then I think you're first three bullets are correct. With respect to your fourth bullet, however, you could use has_many :through or has_and_belongs_to_many to model the relationship between standard_user and deal as discussed in this [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). In the latter case, standard_user's has_many relationship to deal would change to has_and_belongs_to_many.

As for using User subclasses to define relationships, yes, you can do this, but see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for a general discussion of this approach.

Pete

Comment: Just as a warning, I've found that has_and_belongs_to_many, while convenient, is rife with bugs.  Especially on complicated joins it has a tendency to bug out and create garbage SQL.  I've stopped using it completely in favor of `has_many :through`.

Comment: duly noted. thanks a lot. advice from real experience is always much appeciated!

Comment: @charleyc I see what the attributes of the users table look like :user_id/user_login/user_password/user_location.I also see the deals table attributes:deals_name, deals_price...BUT i don't understand what i'd put in the deals_participations table you mention. what would be the attributes (columns) of that table ? If they are: deals_participation_id/user_id/deals_id, i would have a number of lines equal to the number of user multiplied by the number of deals they participate in...which could be enormous and seems uneffective. Am I wrong about the deals_participation table attributes?

Comment: No, you're not wrong.  Those would indeed be the attributes and there would be one row for each unique deal/user pair. Not sure what you think a more compact or effective alternative would be, at least assuming a non-humongous number of deals and users.